# Kendo UI ComboBox for Angular: how to prevent Expected value of type Object error?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-combobox

I am trying to make a Kendo ComboBox for Angular not crash with error "Prevent Expected value of type Object":

```
<kendo-combobox
    formControlName="gender"
    [data]="genders"
    [textField]="'text'"
    [valueField]="'value'"
    [valuePrimitive]="false"
    [filterable]="true"
    [allowCustom]="true"
    required
>
</kendo-combobox>
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kgg1zp?file=app/app.component.ts)

The error can be obtained if the value is deleted and Tab is pressed (combo blur). In fact, by leaving an invalid value in the box, this error will occur.

I will explain below why I am using some settings:

- `textField` and `valueField` - in my application I request complex objects and the selected value will provide some information to other form fields
- `[valuePrimitive]="false"` - the selected value is a complex object
- `[allowCustom]="false"` - I used this to allow the control to receive an initial value that is not among the list. In my application I am using server-side filtering with an empty initial list

When using in the application (server-side filtering) I also receive this error when pushing the arrow button, but I can get rid of this by either ensuring that initial value is within the list of values (ugly) or simply by removing the button.

Any idea about how to make this work?

Comment: How can I reproduce the error in stackblitz? I deleted the selected value and pressed Tab, but everything seems to be fine...

Comment: @Giannis I have just realized that I left allowCustom=false and the default value is not displayed. It should be true. I cannot change it right now (mobile), but I will change it once I reach a laptop.

Comment: Late answer here, but still could help others. You need to set `primitiveValue` to true. If you set `[valuePrimitive]=false`, list is expecting to return an object. But you are trying to return a number (because `gender.value` is a number), even is the provided list is an Object list, you still want to return the `genre.value` attribute, whish is a number/primitive value.

When you set `primitiveValue` to false, list ignores `textField` and `valueField`, as long as it will return the entire object. And that's exactly what happens in the provided stackblitz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Kendo UI for Angular](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/combobox/custom-values/#toc-object-values) you have to use a `valueNormalizer` function to convert what the user actually types into a valid object.

```
public valueNormalizer = (text: Observable<string>) => text.pipe(map((text: string) => {
    return {
        value: this.genders[this.genders.length - 1].value + 1, //whatever value
        text: text
    };
}));
```

Please check the updated [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kgg1zp-s3rpeb?file=app/app.component.ts) and let me know if it is helpful.

Comment: I had simply overlooked that part of the documentation and it makes perfect sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

valueNormalizer didn't work for me at all.

I went for a different solution (I can't post the code here because of security limitations in my company).

We want to allow an initial value and have to allow `[allowCustomer]="true"` because that initial value is not initially a part of the `[data]` array since we fetch it from the server.

I simply pushed the initial value to the `[data]` array and that fixes it. no need for `[allowCustome]="true"`

Comment: For me the proposed solution worked, but I have also tried this one and it is a valid. It is just that it sounds hackish, that's why I thought of getting a better answer.

Comment: I don't think it's hacky. It's just entering the default value to the list. That value normalizer is taking a simple solution and making it complicated (for this scenario at least). Instead of taking care of that default value once, the value normalizer is called for every selection and re-filters the results.